# HTML Nested Form Problem

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a web page using CGI scripting which has a form users need to fill out. The general layout is:

```
<form>
textfield (username)
textfield (password)
textfield (email)
submit button
</form>
```

What I would like to do is add a button that checks to see if the username they've entered is available. My problem is the way I'm trying to go about doing this is by writing:

```
<form>
<form>
textfield (username)
submit button
</form>
textfield (password)
textfield (email)
submit button
</form>
```

This doesn't work, the submit button instead submits the outer form. Here are the things I've considered trying but have not worked:

1. Put a form at the end of the first form. Problem: I have no idea how to align the "validate" button next to the username text field button without making it float which causes a bunch of other issues with the page.
2. Put values on the submit buttons and make the submit do different things based on which button was clicked. Problem: the web page that I want to make a "POST" request to is different based off which button is pressed. Seeing as I put the action="mypage.cgi" in the  portion of the code, and not the button portion, I don't know how to make it go to different sites based on which button I press.

Comment: Just to let you know (since no one else has mentioned it) nested forms are forbidden in HTML and their behaviour is undefined, so they're not even guaranteed to work the same in different browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all it is a good idea to give all forms names.
So you can easily distinguish between forms.

Next, attach onClick even to each button that would call a function with a different paramenter: 1,2,3. Each button would send its own parameter. In the function you just look at the paramenter and submit appropraite form.

```
<form name='form1'>
....
<button type="button" onClick=doIt(1);>Submit</button>
</form>

<form name='form2'>
....
<button type="button" onClick=doIt(2);>Submit</button>
</form>

<form name='form3'>
....
<button type="button" onClick=doIt(3);>Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
function doIt(formid)
{
   if(formid==1)
   {
      document.form1.submit();
   }
   if(formid==2)
   {
      document.form2.submit();
   }

...
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Have multiple submit buttons with different names. Check for each on the post back.

Comment: I posted my problem with that solution as #2

Comment: You can detect what button is clicked in JavaScript then change the action attribute based on that. That's the only way I can see out of the mess.

Answer (score 1):

The approach that I have used for nested forms is to use  tag instead of  tag, 
and then appending the form tags at the time of clicking submit buttons.

I have written a small JQ Plugin-'dynaForm' for the same, and its very easy to implement.
Please refer to ==> http://anupampdhyy.wordpress.com/2014/09/29/dynaform/

and

you can also watch a demo for same at :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CFQia8EsoPQ&feature=youtu.be

I hope this helps you to implement nested forms in your HTML code. :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to make two different form actions, so that you don't submit two completly different values.

Comment: How do I make two different form actions?

Comment: You first make one:
<form action='' method=''>
then put in your first textfield.
Then you can make another one exactly like it, with a different form action, and you will have two different POSTS, with different values.